# How can we show that this normal field is "outward pointing"?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, manifolds-with-boundary, tangent-spaces, submanifold

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $\alpha\in\mathbb N$ and $M$ be a $d$-dimensional embedded $C^\alpha$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ with boundary.

> How can we show that there is a unique $\nu_M:\partial M\to\mathbb R^d$ with$^1$ $$\nu_M(x)\in N_x\:\partial M,\tag1$$ $\left\|\nu_M(x)\right\|=1$ and $$\exists\varepsilon>0:\forall t\in(0,\varepsilon):x+t\nu_M(x)\not\in M\tag2$$ for all $x\in\partial M$?

Let $\phi$ be a $C^1$-diffeomorphism$^1$ from an open subset $\Omega$ of $M$ onto an open subset of $\mathbb H^d:=\mathbb R^{d-1}\times[0,\infty)$. By definition of [$C^1$-differentiability](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3775990/47771), $$\phi_d=\left.\psi\right|_\Omega\tag3$$ for some $\psi\in C^1(O)$ for some open subset $O$ of $\mathbb R^d$ with $\Omega\subseteq O$. Since $\phi(\Omega)\subseteq\mathbb H^d$, $$\psi(\Omega)\subseteq[0,\infty)\tag4.$$ Moreover, since $\phi(\Omega\cap\partial M)=\phi(\Omega)\cap\partial\mathbb H^d\subseteq\partial\mathbb H^d$, $$\psi(\Omega\cap\partial M)\subseteq\{0\}\tag5.$$ Assume $\Omega\cap\partial M\ne\emptyset$ and hence $$\psi(\Omega\cap\partial M)=\{0\}\tag6.$$ Let $x\in\Omega\cap\partial M$. Note that, if $h\in\mathbb R^d$ with $$\langle{\rm D}\phi(x)h,e_d\rangle>0\tag7,$$ then (since $\psi(x)=0$) $$\frac{\psi(x+th)}t\xrightarrow{t\to0}{\rm D}\psi(x)h=\langle{\rm D}\phi(x)h,e_d\rangle>0\tag8$$ by the chain rule and hence $$\psi(x+th)<0\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in(-\varepsilon_1,0)\tag9$$ for some $\varepsilon_1>0$ and $$\psi(x+th)>0\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in(0,\varepsilon_2)\tag{10}$$ for some $\varepsilon_2>0$.

Now let $$\mu_M(x):={{\rm D}\phi(x)}^\ast e_d=\nabla\phi_d(x)=\nabla\psi(x)\tag{11},$$ where $(e_1,\ldots,e_d)$ denotes the standard basis of $\mathbb R^d$. Then $$N_x\:\partial M=\mathbb R\mu_M(x)\tag{12}.$$ Let $$\nu_M(x):=\frac{\mu_M(x)}{\left\|\mu_M(x)\right\|}.$$ Then, obviously, $$\langle{\rm D}\phi(x)\mu_M(x),e_d\rangle=\left\|{{\rm D}\phi(x)}^\ast e_d\right\|^2>0\tag{13}$$ and hence $\nu_M(x)$ satisfies $(2)$.

> How do we need to argue that $\nu_M(x)$ is actually uniquely determined by $(2)$? And how can we show that there is a tubular neighborhood $U$ of $\partial M$ so that $\nu_M$ can be extended to a function in $C^{\alpha-1}(U,\mathbb R^d)$?

I think we should first try to extend $\mu_M$. In order to do that, let $((\Omega_i,\phi_i))_{i\in I}$ be a $C^\alpha$-atlas of $M$ for some nonempty set $I$. As before, $$\langle\phi_i,e_d\rangle=\left.\psi_i\right|_\Omega\tag{14}$$ for some $\psi_i\in C^\alpha(O_i)$ for some open subset $O_i$ of $\mathbb R^d$ with $\Omega_i\subseteq O_i$ for all $i\in I$. Since $\Omega_i$ is an open subset of $M$, we can assume that $$\Omega_i=O_i\cap M\;\;\;\text{for all }i\in Itag{15}.$$ Let $$\mu_i(x):={{\rm D}\phi_i(x)}^\ast e_d=\nabla\psi_i(x)\tag{16}$$ and $$\nu_i(x):=\frac{\mu_i(x)}{\left\|\mu_i(x)\right\|}$$ for $x\in O_i$ and $i\in I$. Let $O:=\bigcup_{i\in I}$.

> Now, the idea is to take $\rho_i\in C_c^\infty(O)$ with $\left.\rho_i\right|_{\partial M}\ge0$ and $\operatorname{supp}\rho_i\subseteq O_i$ for $i\in I$ with $$\partial M\subseteq\left\{\sum_{i\in I}\rho_i=1\right\}\tag{17}.$$ Which assumption do we need to find $(\rho_i)_{i\in I}$? And how can we conclude that $$\overline\mu_M(x):=\sum_{i\in I}\rho_i(x)\mu_M(x)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in O$$ is actually a well-defined extension of $\mu_M$?

I'm unsure how we need to argue that, if $x\in\Omega_i\cap\Omega_j$ for some $i,j\in I$ with $i\ne j$, $\mu_i(x)=\mu_j(x)$. And don't we "count them twice" in $\overline\mu_M(x)$?

---

$T_x\:\partial M$ and $N_x\:\partial M$ denote the tangent and normal space of $\partial M$ at $x$, respectively.

Comment: It does not seem to be the case to me that $(2)$ is an appropriate definition of outward pointing (take, for instance the closed hemisphere, where both unit normal vector fields satisfy $(2)$). Also, $(3)$ does not seem to properly define the normal bundle, since $\phi$ need not be an isometry.

Comment: @Kajelad Regarding $(2)$: Unfortunately, I cannot find a reference in English. However, I don't get why the hemisphere should be a counter example. Do you mean that the points at the "bottom" circle are problematic? Regarding $(3)$: Why should we need $\phi$ to be an isometry? The elements of $N_x\:\partial M$ don't need to be of unit length. Just to be sure, $N_x\:\partial M$ is the orthogonal complement of the tangent space $T_x\:\partial M$.

Comment: Never mind the point about $(2)$, it works fine in codimension $0$. For $(3)$, it need not be the case that $D\phi(x)^*e_d$ is orthogonal to $T_x\partial M$, since $D\phi(x)$ need not preserve inner products.

Comment: @Kajelad ${{\rm D}\phi(x)}^\ast$ *is* orthogonal to $T_x\:\partial M$: If $\psi:=\phi^{-1}$ and $u:=\phi(x)$, then $$T_x\:\partial M={\rm D}\psi(u)\partial\mathbb H^d$$ and now you only need to observe that $${\rm D}\phi(x){\rm D}\psi(u)=\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb R^d}.$$

Comment: $D\phi(x)^*$ preserves the tangent subspace, but not necessarilty it orthogonal compliment. Consider the map $\mathbb{H}^2\to\mathbb{H}^2$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto(x+y,y)$

Comment: @Kajelad By my comment above, $T_x\:\partial M$ is spanned by $$\tau_i:={\rm D}\psi(u)e_i$$ for $i\in\{1,\ldots,d-1\}$. Now $$\langle\tau_i,{\rm D}\phi(x)^\ast e_d\rangle=\langle{\rm D}\phi(x){\rm D}\psi(u)e_i,e_d\rangle=\langle e_i,e_d\rangle=0$$ for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,d-1\}$ and hence ${\rm D}\phi(x)^\ast e_d$ is orthogonal to $T_x\:\partial M$.

Comment: You assume above $\langle D\phi(x)u,D\phi(x)v\rangle=\langle u,v\rangle$, which is only the case if $\phi$ is an isometry.

Comment: @Kajelad No, why do you think I'm assuming this? Note that there is a $\phi$ and a $\psi=\phi^{-1}$.

Comment: My mistake; I mistook $D\phi(x)^*$ for a pullback rather than an adjoint. I don't see any further issues with your definitions. As for showing existence and uniqueness, an equivalent condition to $(2)$ is that a vecor field $\eta$ is outward pointing at $x\in\partial M$ if there is no $C^1$ path $\gamma:[0,\epsilon)\to M$ such that $\dot{\gamma}(0)=\eta$. Then it's a matter of showing each boundary point has two unit normals, and only one satisfies this condition.

Comment: @Kajelad For a moment I thought I was missing something crucial ;) Please take note of my edit. Do you agree so far?

Comment: @Kajelad I've added some further thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each point point $x\in\partial M$, $T_x\partial M$ is a $d-1$ dimensional subspace and thus $N_x\partial M$ contains exactly exactly two vectors of unit norm. Thus, unit normal vector fields are unique iff $(2)$ holds for exactly one of them. You already have everything needed to prove this, since in local coordinates exactly one of them satisfies the inequality $(7)$.

It won't always be possible to extend a normal vector field $\nu$, depending on what definition of submanifold with boundary you are using. For instance, the set
$$
S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x\ge 0,y\ge 0,(x,y)\neq(0,0)\}
$$
Is an embedded submanifold with boundary, but there is no extension of the normal vector field near the origin.

We can, however, always extend $\nu$ provided $\partial M$ is closed $\mathbb{R}^d$. In this case, we can cover $\partial M$ with a collection of boundary charts $(\phi_i,\Omega_i)$ of $\partial M$ which, together with $\mathbb{R^d}\setminus\partial M$, form an open cover of  $\mathbb{R}^d$. We can then define a partition of unity $\rho_i$ subbordinate to this cover. If we can define a local extension $\nu_i:\Omega_i\to\mathbb{R}^n$ for each $i$,  defined in coordinates by $\nu_i(x^1,\dots,x^d)=\nu(x^1\dots,x^{d-1},0)$, then we may define a global extension $\widetilde{\nu}(x)=\sum_i\rho_i\nu_i(x)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. (a) $\partial M$ is always closed in $M$. So, I guess you want it to be closed in $\mathbb R^d$, right? (b) Why can we cover the boundary in this case? (c) I'm mostly intersted in the case where $M$ is bounded and open and hence $\overline M$ is compact. Then we should be able to select the set $I$ in the question such that it is countable. Can we use it then to extend $\mu_M$?

Comment: (d) I'm also unsure why $(11)$ is independent of the choice of $ϕ$. Wouldn't we need to show that if $ϕ_i$ is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism from an open subset $\Omega_i$ of $M$ onto an open subset of $\mathbb H^k$ with $\Omega_1\cap\Omega_2\ne\emptyset$, then ${\rm D}ϕ_1(x)={\rm D}ϕ_2(x)$ for all $x\in\Omega_1\cap\Omega_2$? If $x\in\Omega_1\cap\Omega_2$ and $u_i:=ϕ_i(x)$, then ${\rm D}(ϕ_2\circϕ_1^{-1}(u_1)={\rm D}ϕ_2(x){{\rm D}ϕ_1(x)}^{-1}$ and ${\rm D}(ϕ_1\circϕ_2^{-1})(u_2)={\rm D}ϕ_1(x){{\rm D}ϕ_2(x)}^{-1}$, but I don't know why it should hold ${\rm D}ϕ_1(x)={\rm D}ϕ_2(x)$.

Comment: (a) Yes, I mean closed in $\mathbb{R}^d$. (b-c) Every point $x\in\partial M$ is contained in the domain of a boundary chart $(\phi_x,\Omega_x)$, so we can simply use $\{\Omega_x\}_{x\in\partial M}$ as a covering (this has nicer subcovers/refinements, but they aren't needed for the proof). This covering always exists, but the extension argument doesn't work unless $\mathbb{R}^d\setminus\partial M$ is open. (d) $(11)$ is not independent of coordinates. The idea of the POU argument is that the local extensions need not agree outside of $\partial M$.

Comment: (d) I know, but $\nu_i(x)$ and $\nu_j$ should need to agree if $x\in\Omega_i\cap\Omega_j$. Why is that the case?

Comment: $\nu_i(x)$ and $nu_j(x)$ need only agree if $x\in\partial M$ (since there they are the unique outward unit normal). Otherwise they may differ.

Comment: I've often read that we need to extend $\nu$ to a tubular neighborhood of $\partial M$. Why can't we take any open neighborhood of $\partial M$?

Comment: It's possible to construct an extension to all of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and thus any neighborhood of  $\partial M$, The emphasis on tubular neighborhoods is likely just because tubular neighborhoods can be used to construct the extension.

Comment: Have you a good reference for that at hand, which does consider this extension in the simple case of submanifolds of $\mathbb R^d$?

Comment: I don't know of anything that covers this specific case. The closest I can think of is lemma 2.26 in Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, which covers extensions of smooth $\mathbb{R}^k$ valued functions from closed subsets of arbitrary manifolds.